# jQuery - sort any given JSON chronologically

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, monthcalendar

I have this JSON array which I am trying to render into chartistJs. However the outcome of this JSON is not formatted in chronological order.

```
[
    {"May2021": "181287.56"},
    {"Mar2021": "94824.95"},
    {"Feb2021": "79316.17"},
    {"Apr2021": "107782.89"},
    {"Jan2021": "94802.65"},
    {"Jun2021": "100671.2"}
]
```

The jQuery logic I have is to capture the month values and render it into an X and Y axis series.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var months = {
    Jan: 0,
    Feb: 1,
    Mar: 2,
    Apr: 3,
    May: 4,
    Jun: 5,
    Jul: 6,
    Aug: 7,
    Sep: 8,
    Oct: 9,
    Nov: 10,
    Dec: 11
  };

  $.ajax({
    url:
      "https://flci9mttga.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/poc/costAggregateAPI",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (response) {
      //console.log(response);
      var arrLabels = [],
        arrShortLabels = [],
        arrSeries = [],
        arrSortedSerise = [];

      $.map(response, function (item, index) {
        var dtM = item.substring(0, 3);
        var dtY = item.substring(3, 7);

        arrLabels.push(new Date(dtY, months[dtM]));
        arrShortLabels.push(new Date(dtY, months[dtM]).toDateString("MMYYYY"));
        arrSeries.push(item.Y);
      });

      arrShortLabels.sort(function (x, y) {
        let a = new Date(x),
          b = new Date(y);
        return a - b;
      });

      var data = {
        labels: arrShortLabels,
        series: arrSeries
      };
      demo.initDocChartist(data);
    }
  });
});
```

The code for ChartistJS plugin is as below -

```
initDocChartist: function (data) {
    var dataSales = {
      labels: data.labels,
      series: [data.series]
    };

    var optionsSales = {
      lineSmooth: false,
      low: 0,
      high: 120000,
      showArea: true,
      height: "245px",
      axisX: {
        showGrid: false
      },
      lineSmooth: Chartist.Interpolation.simple({
        divisor: 3
      }),
      showLine: false,
      showPoint: false
    };

    var responsiveSales = [
      [
        "screen and (max-width: 640px)",
        {
          axisX: {
            labelInterpolationFnc: function (value) {
              return value[0];
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    ];

    Chartist.Line("#chartHours", dataSales, optionsSales, responsiveSales);
```

Would appreciate if anyone can help me out with this

Comment: If you can make sure that those objects always contain only one key which represents a date string, you can use `Object.keys(o)[0]` to access the key. Then parse the key with a date library or even just with the Date constructor (I would not do that...) `new Date(key)` and then you can compare the dates with `date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use a standard format for dates, such as ISO

People who enter data manually and do not know about programming sometimes just write dates as "Mar2020", because they are always intending to interpret it only manually.

However as you are a programmer, you should try to always store information in an unambiguous manner that is easy to interpret automatically.

I suggest you convert the month words + year, into the following numerical format:

```
 yyyy-mm
```

This is good because:

- it is unambiguous for programmers who are coming from any human language
- it is understood by the general population
- if you sort it alphabetically, it comes automatically in date order
- it is the first part of the ISO 1601 date format which is widely understood and used in computing.

#### You are nearly there

Instead of converting with `toDateString` applying arbitrary non-sortable scheme such as "mmyyyy", with

```
.toDateString("MMYYYY")
```

... try instead:

```
.toISOString().slice(0,7)
```

The resulting structure is just a string, which means it is

- easy to store unambiguously
- easy to interpret
- free of time zone problems sometimes seen with Date types

#### You can post your code with the < > icon in the editor

People will find it easier to test your code, and will therefore be more encouraged to amend it for you.